# ¿Como puedo relacionar con array multidimensionales?

Tags: php, array

Hola muy buenos dias a todos,estoy haciendo un cronjob para enviar correos sobre que alguna direccion ip de un cliente en especifico esta sufriendo de algun ataque hasta el momento todo bien pero cuando quiero relacionar la direccion ip con el cliente es donde me detengo. desconozco mucho sobre los arrays de php de hecho no me gusta

Por ejemplo este cliente tiene estas direcciones ip

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que busco es que cuando yo levante un correo se envie con el nombre del cliente mas con su direccion ip que esta siendo afectada ¿como puedo relacionarlos?

```html
$return_antihack = [
    {
        "33": {
            "id": "33",
            "client_id": "1",
            "order_id": "28",
            "product_id": "19",
            "parent_id": "0",
            "date_created": "2022-11-28",
            "domain": "",
            "server_id": "0",
            "payment_module": "0",
            "firstpayment": "8225.00",
            "total": "8225.00",
            "billingcycle": "Monthly",
            "billingtype": "PrePay",
            "next_due": "2022-12-28",
            "due_day": "28",
            "expires": "2022-12-28",
            "autorenew": "0",
            "next_invoice": "2022-12-28",
            "status": "Active",
            "label": "",
            "username": "mengana",
            "password": "111111",
            "autosuspend": "0",
            "autosuspend_date": "0000-00-00",
            "rootpassword": "11111",
            "date_changed": "2022-11-28 16:57:50",
            "synch_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "synch_error": "0",
            "user_error": "0",
            "domain_error": "0",
            "notes": "",
            "manual": "0",
            "extra_details": [],
            "commitment_date": "",
            "contract_id": "0",
            "discount_id": "",
            "firstname": "mengana",
            "lastname": "ruiz",
            "ip": "167.114.147.91",
            "additional_ip": [
                "85.144.117.199"
            ],
            "source": "vpsdata"
        }
    },
    {
        "35": {
            "id": "35",
            "client_id": "2",
            "order_id": "30",
            "product_id": "19",
            "parent_id": "0",
            "date_created": "2022-11-28",
            "domain": "",
            "server_id": "0",
            "payment_module": "0",
            "firstpayment": "8225.00",
            "total": "8225.00",
            "billingcycle": "Monthly",
            "billingtype": "PrePay",
            "next_due": "2022-12-28",
            "due_day": "28",
            "expires": "2022-12-28",
            "autorenew": "0",
            "next_invoice": "2022-12-28",
            "status": "Active",
            "label": "",
            "username": "fulanito",
            "password": "00000",
            "autosuspend": "0",
            "autosuspend_date": "0000-00-00",
            "rootpassword": "0000",
            "date_changed": "2022-11-28 16:42:07",
            "synch_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "synch_error": "0",
            "user_error": "0",
            "domain_error": "0",
            "notes": "",
            "manual": "0",
            "extra_details": [],
            "commitment_date": "",
            "contract_id": "0",
            "discount_id": "",
            "firstname": "fulano",
            "lastname": "juarez",
            "ip": "114.78.207.128",
            "additional_ip": [
                ""
            ],
            "source": "vpsdata"
        }
    }
];
foreach ($return_antihack as $index_return_antihack => $value_return_antihack) {

    foreach ($value_return_antihack as $key_return_antihack => $val_return_antihack) {
        $return_antihack_result[] = $value_return_antihack[$key_return_antihack];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partes de una base equivocada, pues eso que intentas tratar como un array es un archivo json, que puedes convertir a array para su posterior tratamiento en PHP, de este modo:

```
<?php
$json = '[
    {
        "33": {
            "id": "33",
            "client_id": "1",
            "order_id": "28",
            "product_id": "19",
            "parent_id": "0",
            "date_created": "2022-11-28",
            "domain": "",
            "server_id": "0",
            "payment_module": "0",
            "firstpayment": "8225.00",
            "total": "8225.00",
            "billingcycle": "Monthly",
            "billingtype": "PrePay",
            "next_due": "2022-12-28",
            "due_day": "28",
            "expires": "2022-12-28",
            "autorenew": "0",
            "next_invoice": "2022-12-28",
            "status": "Active",
            "label": "",
            "username": "mengana",
            "password": "111111",
            "autosuspend": "0",
            "autosuspend_date": "0000-00-00",
            "rootpassword": "11111",
            "date_changed": "2022-11-28 16:57:50",
            "synch_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "synch_error": "0",
            "user_error": "0",
            "domain_error": "0",
            "notes": "",
            "manual": "0",
            "extra_details": [],
            "commitment_date": "",
            "contract_id": "0",
            "discount_id": "",
            "firstname": "mengana",
            "lastname": "ruiz",
            "ip": "167.114.147.91",
            "additional_ip": [
                "85.144.117.199"
            ],
            "source": "vpsdata"
        }
    },
    {
        "35": {
            "id": "35",
            "client_id": "2",
            "order_id": "30",
            "product_id": "19",
            "parent_id": "0",
            "date_created": "2022-11-28",
            "domain": "",
            "server_id": "0",
            "payment_module": "0",
            "firstpayment": "8225.00",
            "total": "8225.00",
            "billingcycle": "Monthly",
            "billingtype": "PrePay",
            "next_due": "2022-12-28",
            "due_day": "28",
            "expires": "2022-12-28",
            "autorenew": "0",
            "next_invoice": "2022-12-28",
            "status": "Active",
            "label": "",
            "username": "fulanito",
            "password": "00000",
            "autosuspend": "0",
            "autosuspend_date": "0000-00-00",
            "rootpassword": "0000",
            "date_changed": "2022-11-28 16:42:07",
            "synch_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "synch_error": "0",
            "user_error": "0",
            "domain_error": "0",
            "notes": "",
            "manual": "0",
            "extra_details": [],
            "commitment_date": "",
            "contract_id": "0",
            "discount_id": "",
            "firstname": "fulano",
            "lastname": "juarez",
            "ip": "114.78.207.128",
            "additional_ip": [
                ""
            ],
            "source": "vpsdata"
        }
    }
]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$salida = [];
foreach (array_values($array) as $clientes) {
    foreach (array_values($clientes) as $datos_cliente) {
        $salida[$datos_cliente['client_id']]['nombre_completo'] = $datos_cliente['firstname'].' '.$datos_cliente['lastname']."\n";
        $salida[$datos_cliente['client_id']]['IP'] = $datos_cliente['ip'];
        $salida[$datos_cliente['client_id']]['IPs_adicionales'] = implode(",", $datos_cliente['additional_ip']);
    }
}
print_r($salida);
```

Lo cual te va a devolver esto, donde el índice es el código de cliente (client_id):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre_completo] => mengana ruiz

            [IP] => 167.114.147.91
            [IPs_adicionales] => 85.144.117.199
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre_completo] => fulano juarez

            [IP] => 114.78.207.128
            [IPs_adicionales] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: si me funciono amigo gracias